# ошибка 403 при git -push

Tags: github

Уже перерыл тырнет по данной ошибке, но там все связанно с чем-то другим, кто-то пишет что нужно добавить в setting - c0llaborators или в диспетчере учетных записей добавить аккаунт гита, но по ошибке вижу что пытается авторизоваться по другой ссылке, но как перелогиниться не знаю. как поменять на https://github.com/c0o1errr, а не на https://github.com/c0o1errr/basejava?
[image: такая вот ошибка] через токен тоже не получается.

Comment: Гитхаб запрещает использовать пароль для авторизации в git https://www.opennet.ru/opennews/art.shtml?num=55632

Comment: А про «через токен тоже не получается» нужно больше подробностей, где что как конкретно не получается?

Comment: все разобрался)